# Group docker compose services (multiple files)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For now in `docker-compose.yml` I have grouped services by naming them like `api`, `api-mysql`, `blog`, `blog-mysql`, `blog-redis`, `frontend`, `frontend-something` etc. Then main services (api, blog) has `depends_on` with listed needed services. And it works fine.

But while file grows, it becomes less and less readable (because it's long). I'm wondering if there is better way to group services for such scenario? Can I for example have `docker-compose.yml` with global services like phpMyAdmin and inside include specific ones `docker-compose-api.yml` and `docker-compose-blog.yml`?

I cannot find if is there a better (more readable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker **[multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)**. You need to create unique Dockerfiles for separated services, here the **image** means: Docker build the image with this name
After that you can build the environment with **docker-compose up -d --build** command. This command need to run only one (except when build failed) after the build successfully finished you can use your services with general commands **docker-compose start/stop/restart**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
      target: api
    image: api:latest
    ...
    ...

  blog:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.blog
      target: blog
    image: blog:latest
    ...
    ...

  frontend:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.frontend
      target: frontend
    image: frontend:latest

  api-mysql:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.api-mysql
      target: api-mysql
    image: api-mysql:latest
    ...
    ...
    depends_on:
      - api
  ..
  ...
  ...
  etc...
```

Comment: But I'm not sure how this helps here. It's still all services in single file. Just instead image:version I use dockerfile with context, target etc. So in the end file will be even longer

Comment: Hmm, it's right. Other option is extended docker-compose. I think this is closer to your idea https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to include `docker-compose` file into other one.
**BUT** if you want to [extend some of your services from other file](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6087422/adam-p), welcome...

As `Adam P.` mentioned, the only way to do it more clean is to make complex command like `docker-compose -f docker-compose-core.yml -f docker-compose-api.prod.yml -f docker-compose-frontend.prod.yml up -d`.

*PS: Actually, hate it a bit. Now I have to create a script that just runs this large command.*

Answer (score 0):

You *could* invoke docker compose with multiple -f files.  I don't know that it'd be more readable, but you could...

`docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.database.yml -f docker-compose.microservices.yml -f docker-compose.test-harness.yml ...`

```
docker-compose.yml:
# Just the app!
services:
  app:
    ...
```

```
docker-compose.database.yml:
# Database things
services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      - some_database
      - elasticsearch
      - memcached

  some_database:
    ...

  elasticsearch:
    ...

  memcached:
    ...
...
```

etc.

We always use Makefiles with docker so we end up with things like:

- `make app` # launch the app with the databases so you can do basic stuff
- `make app_with_services` # launch the app with the databases and services
- `make test` # launch app with everything including the test harness and run the tests